# How to fill sockaddr_storage?

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to use `sockaddr_storage` struct in my application. I am curious how to fill it. For example I have following code:

```
sHostAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sHostAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (cpIPAddress);
```

How can I replace it if I use `sockaddr_storage` struct? I know that there are some char arrays, and I suppose I can get an equivalent code using some array index offsets?

Thanks on advance.

Comment: The "correct" way is to not fill it at all. Take whatever `getaddrinfo` gives to you, or, take whatever `recvfrom` gives to you. Whatever ends up being in the structure after you've called one of these functions is correct and you need not worry about.

Answer (score 9):

The name is the hint, `sockaddr_storage` is for storage only, not for accessing.  Use in a union with specific protocol structures:

```
union {
  struct sockaddr         sa;
  struct sockaddr_in      s4;
  struct sockaddr_in6     s6;
  struct sockaddr_storage ss;
} addr;
memset (&addr.s4, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
addr.s4.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.s4.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

or `memcpy`, e.g.

```
struct sockaddr_storage storage;
struct sockaddr_in sin;

memset (&sin, 0, sizeof (sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("127.0.0.1");
memcpy (&storage, &sin, sizeof (sin));
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast it. If for example your `sin_family` is `AF_INET6`, you can cast the `sockaddr_storage` pointer to a `sockaddr_in6` pointer and then fill in whatever you need to.

It is just a general socket address holding structure, big enough to hold either
`struct sockaddr_in` or `struct sockaddr_in6` data or any future `sockaddr_xxx`..

You can find one example usage here: http://www.kame.net/newsletter/19980604/

Note that sometimes developers will redefine this structure to use a union instead. That can have some side effects and isn't cross-platform.

Comment: Note that casting breaks aliasing rules so one must disable strict aliasing optimisations in the compiler.