# Convert UInt32 / UInt8[16] to SOCKADDR_STORAGE

Tags: c++

I'll be utilizing either an IPv4 address in the form of a UInt32 or an IPv6 in the form of UInt8[16]. The current approach is to convert them into a string and then use `WSAStringToAddress` to convert to a `PSOCKADDR_STORAGE`. I was wondering if there is a standard implementation to cut converting to a string out. There will be a flag identifying the address family so I'll have that to go off at the least.

```c++
DWORD ConvertStringToAddress(_In_ LPWSTR AddressString,
    _Out_ PSOCKADDR_STORAGE Address)
{
    DWORD Status = NO_ERROR;
    INT AddressSize;

    AddressSize = sizeof(*Address);
    Address->ss_family = AF_INET;

    if (WSAStringToAddress(AddressString,
        AF_INET,
        NULL,
        (PSOCKADDR)Address,
        &AddressSize))
    {
        AddressSize = sizeof(*Address);
        Address->ss_family = AF_INET6;

        if (WSAStringToAddress(AddressString,
            AF_INET6,
            NULL,
            (PSOCKADDR)Address,
            &AddressSize))
        {
            // handle error
        }
    }

    return Status;
```

Comment: When you have a UInt32 you want to convert to a IPv4 address, don't you. You can just assign the ip_addr member of the SOCKADDR_IN struct with the `htons` macro. Something Similar should be possible with IPv6.

Comment: I'm not trying to convert it to a SOCKADDR_IN, rather a SOCKADRR_STORAGE. Is it possible to cast one as the either?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883030/how-to-fill-sockaddr-storage